# Tablesorter filter dropdown options with values different than their labels

Tags: ajax, filter, server-side, tablesorter

Tablesorter automatically builds the the `select` element for a column filter based on the settings in `filter_formatter`. Is it possible for tablesorter to set the `<option>` value attribute to be different than the label in a dropdown `<select>` filter in tablesorter when using ajax? It seems that tablesorter sets both to be the same.

For example, I'd like to be able to have the following dropdown to filter on languages:

```
<select>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

Using ajax, the two-letter value is used to query the database, but the full language name is better to show users for understandability.

Comment: Hey lindon, there isn't a method available to allow different option values & text, yet. Please open an issue ;)

Comment: @Mottie this is what I want to do. is this available yet and how do I implement it?

Comment: Try this - https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource

Answer (score 0):

What you have written above should work. When getting the selected value using javascript, find the select element, (call it `var selectBox`), and then `selectBox.value` will be the 'value' of the selected element. So if 'English' is what's showing as chosen, `selectBox.value` will equal 'en'.

Comment: Thanks for your response - this is actually a tablesorter-specific question so I've edited the original question to hopefully make that clearer.